# How to merge changes to another svn repo?

Tags: svn, merge, fork

I have two svn repositories containing the same project, the first one is the trunk (the main place where development takes place), the second was forked off of the master a few revisions ago and contains a slightly customized version.

Now I have made changes to the main repo and would like to merge these changes to the forked one.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

I've tried working with `svn diff` and `patch` but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: Some clarification, because I notice Git-like phrases: do you have two versions of the `master` branch, each of which points to two completely separate SVN repositories? You say you forked the `master` branch - did you mean you [created a branch off `master`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.html), which resides in the same repository?

Comment: @SameerSingh Sorry for the confusing phrasing, I have exactly 2 svn repos and 0 git repos. The second repo holds a fork of the first one.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast - "Fork" isn't SVN lingua also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd /home/user/repo-branch
svn merge -r PREV:HEAD svn://localhost/repo/
```

did the trick. `PREV` and `HEAD` can also be replaced with actual revision numbers.

Comment: I'm surprised that worked - unless both `repo-branch` and `trunk` are in the same repository ...

Comment: @SameerSingh they're not. `repo-branch` is at `svn://localhost/repo-branch`. They're two completely seperate repositories, they just have a similar file structure.

Comment: Interesting - what version of SVN are you using on the server, and what is the version of the client? I am going to test this out at home. :)

Comment: @SameerSingh `svn, version 1.6.12 (r955767)` / `svnserve, version 1.6.12 (r955767)`

Comment: Could you let me know if the UUIDs of both repositories are the same or not?

Comment: @SameerSingh `trunk = 04b3d636-d976-44d5-af04-4ef01aad09ec` / `branch = ad93767e-1643-4945-82d3-b0da22415453`. So no, they're not.

Answer (score 1):

Link branch from Repo1 to any node (outside branch in question) of Repo2 (using svn:externals) and you can after it diff or even merge subtrees of single repo